# Needs to active some apache cordova plugin for use window.openDatabase?

Tags: android, cordova, web-sql

Well, I made a webapp using "web database". I have installed on my chrome browser and it works fine; but when I try to install on my android cellphone, get an error like: [object SQLTransaction].

I don't know if I need to active some phonegap plugin to use the storage on cellphone. Here is a little bit of my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", consumo_phoneReady, false);

function consumo_phoneReady(){

  dbShell = window.openDatabase("my_db", "1.0", "database App", 1000000);
  dbShell.transaction(consumo_setupTables,dbErrorHandler,consumo_get_all_ready());
}
```

I get the error message when run the function "consumo_phoneReady()" ie the funcion dbErrorHandler

Comment: AtanuCSE is right about not needing the wrappers.

Its hard to know what the error might be... since we don't see any of that code. 
Try remote debugging so you can find out more about the error... it could be anything in your setupTables which is causing it. You could console.log each tx.executeSQL and output success or failure to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

```
transaction(consumo_setupTables,dbErrorHandler,consumo_get_all_ready());
```

I don't think transaction function takes 3 parameters. it takes 2.

```
transaction(workmethod,errormethod)
```

For example [WebSQL example](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/tutorials/w3c_tutorial/storage_tutorial/web_sql_executing_async.htm)
No plugins required to use webSQL

But if you want to use sqlite wrappers, then use [this plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

Complete documentation available in the plugin link